# Google calendar not inserting event php with custom form

Tags: php, css, html, forms, google-calendar-api

I have a custom form that i am trying to write the fields to Google Calendar using php.

When I submit my form and it writes to the database but i need to write to Google calendar as well.

I debug the code and it stops at  the insert statement create event code

```
$createdEvent = $service->events->insert("junkpolice2060@gmail.com", $newEvent);
```

I hard coded the calendar id to see if it will go but no go every time It stops here.

please help here is the full code

```
require_once   "/var/www/www.junkpolice.com/html/components/com_osservicesbooking/google-  api-php-client-master/src/Google/Client.php";
require_once        "/var/www/www.junkpolice.com/html/components/com_osservicesbooking/google-api-php-client-master/src/Google/Service.php";


$client_id = '1045785081711- 95hsip42q972lgif5ib744ctrejj9kh3.apps.googleusercontent.com'; 
$Email_address = 'calendarosbooking@calendarproject1189.iam.gserviceaccount.com'; 
$key_file_location =   '/var/www/www.junkpolice.com/html/components/com_osservicesbooking/Calendar   Project-e0174e023f1a.p12'; 
$gCalenderID = 'junkpolice2060@gmail.com';


try {

 $client = new Google_Client(); 

$client->setApplicationName("CalendarProject");

$client->setClientId($client_id);

$client->setAssertionCredentials( 
new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
        $Email_address,
        array("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"),
        file_get_contents($key_file_location),
            'notasecret','http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer',false,false

)

);

  }

  catch (RuntimeException $e) {
    return 'Problem authenticating Google Calendar:'.$e->getMessage();
}


$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);    
$newEvent = new Google_Service_Calendar_Event();
$newEvent->setSummary($Service);
$newEvent->setLocation($Address);
$newEvent->setDescription($Notes);
$event_start = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$event_start->setDateTime($startTime);
$newEvent->setStart($event_start);
$event_end = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventDateTime();
$event_end->setDateTime($EndTime);
$newEvent->setEnd($event_end);

$createdEvent = null;


  try {

    $createdEvent = $service->events-      >insert("junkpolice2060@gmail.com", $newEvent);


    $createdEvent_id= $createdEvent->getId();

  $db->setQuery("Update #__app_sch_order_items set gcalendar_event_id = '$createdEvent_id' where id = '$order_item_id'");
  $db->query();

  } catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
  //logIt("svgcal_v3,".$e->getMessage()); 
  echo $e->getMessage();
  exit;
  }
```

Comment: any error messages or more information on the server response? please update the question.

Comment: It would help a lot if you can provide the error that is being shown.